# The cocoon protocol can not be used outside an environment

Tags: tomcat, protocols, pipeline, apache-cocoon

I am facing one issue with integration of cocoon pipeline and CocoonPipelineCronJob scheduler.

My cocoon.xconf snap code as below

```
<trigger name="pipeline-writetest"
             target="org.apache.cocoon.components.cron.CronJob/writetimecron"
             concurrent-runs="false">
             <cron>10 * * ? * *</cron>
</trigger> 
</triggers>
<component  role="org.apache.cocoon.components.cron.CronJob/writetimecron"
            class="org.apache.cocoon.components.cron.CocoonPipelineCronJob"
            logger="cron.writetimecron">
        <sleep>10</sleep>
    <pipeline>writetime</pipeline>
</component>
and my pipeline configure in sitemap.xmap as below
<map:pipeline internal-only="false">
        <map:match pattern="writetime">
            .....<!-- all generator,transformer and serialier code ..-->
        </map:match>
</map:pipeline>
```

> Information Tomcat:
>   apache-tomcat-6.0.30 Cocoon : 2.1 and
>   my pipeline is working well if i
>   accessing it externally ..

**but if i am calling this pipeline from my cronjob then i am getting below error in cocoon.log**

```
INFO  (2011-02-06) 12:54.10:018 [cron] (Unknown-URI) Unknown-Thread/QuartzJobExecutor: Executing cron job named 'pipeline-writetest'
ERROR (2011-02-06) 12:54.10:019 [cron] (Unknown-URI) Unknown-Thread/QuartzJobExecutor: Cron job name 'pipeline-writetest' died.
java.net.MalformedURLException: The cocoon protocol can not be used outside an environment.
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:119)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.excalibur.source.impl.SourceResolverImpl.resolveURI(SourceResolverImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.CocoonComponentManager.resolveURI(CocoonComponentManager.java:558)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.CocoonComponentManager.resolveURI(CocoonComponentManager.java:541)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.cron.CocoonPipelineCronJob.execute(CocoonPipelineCronJob.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.component.ComponentProxyGenerator$ComponentInvocationHandler.invoke(ComponentProxyGenerator.java:143)
    at $Proxy6.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.cron.QuartzJobExecutor.execute(QuartzJobExecutor.java:103)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Please do let me know if you face same issue ago or you are knowing solution of this .

Comment: actually, in my application ..i am calling my pipeline through cronjob and my cronjob is running,trigger on every 10 secs ..

Comment: Is the <trigger> section enclosed in the following component declaration?

<component class="org.apache.cocoon.components.cron.CocoonQuartzJobScheduler"
        role="org.apache.cocoon.components.cron.JobScheduler">

The CocoonQuartzJobScheduler is important, since this class is the one setting up the environment that is reported to be missing in your stack trace.

This was issue with my question and i got answer from Sylvain and its resolved by using the CocoonQuartzJobScheduler .

Comment: Happy you solved it. Though others, like I, might be interested in knowing what the answer was ;-)